# Figuring out how c++ pointers of polymorphic types work?

Tags: c++, pointers

On windows visual studio compiler I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A
{
public:
     A() : m_i(0) { }

protected:
    int m_i;
};

class B
{
public:
    B() : m_d(0.0) { }

protected:
    double m_d;
};

class C : public A, public B
{
public:
    C() : m_c('a') { }
private:
    char m_c;
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    A *pa = &c;
    B *pb = &c;

    std::cout << "&c address:  " << &c << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pa address:  " << pa << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pb address:  " << pb << std::endl;

    bool paSame(pa == &c);
    bool pbSame = (pb == &c);
    bool pbpaSame = (reinterpret_cast<char*>(pa) == reinterpret_cast<char*>(pb));

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "paSame:   " << paSame << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pbSame:   " << pbSame << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pbpaSame: " << pbpaSame << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now on my pc when I run it I get this output:

```
&c address:  0084FAA4
pa address:  0084FAA4
pb address:  0084FAAC

paSame:   1
pbSame:   1
pbpaSame: 0
```

Why is the &c and address of pa the same, is it because in the layout of the object in memory that A's data comes first?

I understand why pb is offset by 8 bytes, as its pointing to the part of memory in the object for that type.  The pointers printed out are different however this line still evaluates to true:

```
bool pbSame = (pb == &c);
```

Why is that?  It makes sense since they the same object but what is the rules on this?  Since the next line (as expected comparing pointers of pa and pb) is showing that the pointers are different.

Comment: There are no polymorphic types here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `(pb == &c)` evaluates to `true` due to auto conversion rules. `&c` is converted to `B*`, which points to the `B` part of `c`, before the comparison is made.

From the C++ Draft Standard N3337:

> **4.10 Pointer conversions**
>
> 3 A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv* `D`”, where `D` is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to *cv* `B`”, where `B` is a base class (Clause 10) of `D`. If `B` is an inaccessible (Clause 11) or ambiguous (10.2) base class of `D`, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. The result of the conversion is a pointer to the base class subobject of the derived class object.

Comment: Having trouble understanding/reading this: I am understanding that its saying that pointers can be automatically converted in case of going from derived to base class, but in the comparison expression, is &c not going from a base to derived (which could be wrong) would be an odd choice for automatic conversion?

Comment: @Chanakya, type of '&c` is `C*`, which is converted to `B*` before the comparison. It is auto converted from a derived type pointer to a base type pointer.